# Как научиться правильно строить алгоритмы?

Tags: алгоритм

Недавно я решил проверить себя насколько хорошо я умею программировать(программирую на Java) , и мне сказали что я не умею составлять правильный алгоритм программы. И сказали то что я неплохо думаю, но у меня знание по построениям алгоритмов 0 и срочно надо исправить это, и научиться правильно их реализовывать и использовать.

Вы как профессионалы своего дела, можете посоветовать с чего именно нужно начать изучение алгоритмов? Я посмотрел список алгоритмов в википедии, но увы, там слишком много информации, да и многое непонятно.

Я знаю то что для алгоритмов нужна практика, но как начать изучение и практику, я не знаю...

Comment: А вы уже работаете джавером или пока учитесь ?

Comment: @faoxis нет, пока что не работаю 2 курс только окончил.. Учусь еще

Comment: по решайте задачи на ресурсах соответствующих, например [здесь](http://acm.timus.ru/) начиная с самых простых

Comment: @ampawd Хмм, интересно) там неважно да на каком языке программировании его решать?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT важно, есть список поддерживаемых языков на которых будут приниматься решения. Но их достаточно много, даже функциональные есть, так что волноваться не стоит